# Transaction validation cost

Tags: block, transaction-verification, block-size-increase

what relation is between transaction size or a number of input and validation cost? for example, It's o(n) or o(n^2)?

Comment: That depends on which (and the amount of) opcodes used and there is no concrete answer.